# Unable to resolve "No address associated with hostname" on azure web service

Tags: python, azure, flask

I have built a solution using flask where, user can send mail to my company mail box. The main code written on application.py is below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mail import Mail, Message


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    MAIL_SERVER='My Company SMTP MAIL SERVER',
    MAIL_PORT=My Company SMTP PORT NUMBER,
    # MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
    MAIL_USERNAME='XXXXX.YYYY@mycompanyname.com',
)
mail = Mail(app)


@app.route('/')
def mailSend():
    try:
        msg = Message("Send Mail Tutorial!",
                      sender="XXXXX.YYYY@mycompanyname.com",
                      recipients=["ZZZ.WWW@mycompanyname.com"])
        msg.html = render_template('linkPage.html')
        mail.send(msg)
        return 'Mail sent!'
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e))
        print(e)
        return 'error'
```

The sender mail address is shared mail and does not need password to send any mail. I already tested the solution on my pycharm IDE and worked totally fine without any issue. However, its throwing error on azure app service after deploying over there. Its saying **gaierror'> [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname**

Any suggestion on this please let me know.

FYI, I didnt mention my company SMTP server name and port number for data sensitivity

the whole error message is below

```
2020-06-10T19:51:09.550551502Z gaierror'>
2020-06-10T19:51:09.550574904Z [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
2020-06-10T19:51:09.550588505Z 172.16.1.1 - - [10/Jun/2020:19:51:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "ReadyForRequest/1.0 (LocalCache)"
2020-06-10T19:51:09.625531116Z gaierror'>
2020-06-10T19:51:09.625552217Z [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
2020-06-10T19:51:09.625557718Z 172.16.1.1 - - [10/Jun/2020:19:51:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "https://portal.azure.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-10T19:51:09.697248520Z gaierror'>
2020-06-10T19:51:09.697270022Z [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
2020-06-10T19:51:09.697276022Z 172.16.1.1 - - [10/Jun/2020:19:51:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "ReadyForRequest/1.0 (AppInit)"
2020-06-10T19:51:09.839063624Z 172.16.1.1 - - [10/Jun/2020:19:51:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://azureoutlookdemo.azurewebsites.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: some servers may block access to other servers - to stop spamers.

Comment: i have put the whole error message from azure log

Comment: if, anyone can help please reply once.